# Assigning the value for dropdown list by default

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have locally assigned  country state city values in `$scope.countries` and passing it to backend, now in $scope.getValue() I will get values for the country state city from backend .But I am unable to assign the values i am getting from backend response to my ng-model `$scope.countrySrc`by default.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">



  <label for="country">Country *</label>
  <select id="country" ng-model="countrySrc" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  <label for="state">State *</label>
  <select id="state" ng-disabled="!countrySrc" ng-model="stateSrc" ng-options="state for (state,city) in countrySrc" ng-change="GetSelectedState()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
  <select id="city" ng-disabled="!countrySrc || !stateSrc" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in stateSrc">
    <option value=''>Select</option>

  </select>

  <script>
    angular
      .module('myApp', [])
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
      })
      .controller('testController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {


          $scope.countries = {

            'USA': {
              'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
              'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
              'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
            },
            'India': {
              'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
              'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
              'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
            },
            'Australia': {
              'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
              'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
            }
          };

          $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
            $scope.strCountry = $scope.countrySrc;
          };
          $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
            $scope.strState = $scope.stateSrc;
          };
UserService.getProfile.then(function (response) {


         $scope.strCountry = response.json.response.profile.country;
        };


    $scope.getProfile();
      ])
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Userservice.jS:

```
function getProfile(profile){
        return $http.post(url+'?request=' + JSON.stringify(profile)).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error in saving profile details'));
    }
```

Response from backend:

```
     {"response":{"json":{"session_id":"498","profile":
{"country":"Afghanistan",
"state":"Badakhshan",
"city":"Eshkashem",
"pincode":"54564","rolemandatory":1},"roles":[]}}}
```

Comment: where is your api call? what is `response` in your question?

Comment: where did you call that service?

Comment: I call service seprately in userservice.js

Comment: you have taken `response` in your `getValues` function in your code. but response is not defined anywhere in your controller.

Comment: Hi , I defined response in controller, just to display here. I given the piece of code.  And from backend when I am getting back the value couldn't show in the dropdown ng-model.that is the only problem I have.

Comment: You can find the updated code with response defined too.

Answer (score 0):

> Down voters please read all comments below's answer first, i have just
>   update it from his requirement to guide him.

I have made one plunker for you : Please refer it : [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oHwryfSTaz3MfpsdPebr?p=preview)

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
  })
  .controller('testController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {


      $scope.countries = {

        'USA': {
          'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
          'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
          'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
        },
        'India': {
          'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
          'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
          'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
        },
        'Australia': {
          'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
          'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
        }
      };

      $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
        $scope.strCountry = $scope.countrySrc;
      };
      $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
        $scope.strState = $scope.stateSrc;
      };

      $scope.getValues = function() {
        $scope.strCountry = $scope.countrySrc;
      };
      $scope.getValues();
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">



  <label for="country">Country *</label>
  <select id="country" ng-model="countrySrc" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>


  <label for="state">State *</label>
  <select id="state" ng-disabled="!countrySrc" ng-model="stateSrc" ng-options="state for (state,city) in countrySrc" ng-change="GetSelectedState()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
  <select id="city" ng-disabled="!countrySrc || !stateSrc" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in stateSrc">
    <option value=''>Select</option>

  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi , I understand what you meant , but the problem I am talking about is , locally I have this country state city and saving it to backend . And from backend when I am getting back the value couldn't show in the dropdown ng-model.

Comment: check it now i have define promises for that, not a proper direct in a working condition but you can use it in your code.

Comment: Hi, I dont understand the logic. Actually I am using local data in my html page ,and passing the values to backend.from backend when I get back values , I need to show selected country in ng-model as well dropdown needs to populate value. But this logic assign values of $scope.countries as India , if I select country as India.

Comment: of course because of your existing code i have used,so that  you have to play around this, otherwise let me know i can provide you another working code snippet not from your's. I will create on my own like as your scenarios

Comment: It will be good if you provide another code snippet, anyway I will look onto your logic and play around too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127592/discussion-between-nicoleta-wilskon-and-jigar7521).

Answer (score 0):

To assign value to drop-down default you need to assign it to modal of select box.

If it don't work you need to iterate select box drop-down option and match with your back-end saved country. then assign matched iterated option to select box modal.